# Empty Cart on just mobile and Microsoft edge browser

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

any help highly appriciated, i can add products from chrome and mozillah but cadding to cart not wokring on ms edge and safari also not on ios devices.

highly highly appriciated any help[image]
http://www.hustler-luxury.com/

Comment: You should be more specific on how you are adding products to your cart, but either way this is certainly an issue with your theme and not woocommerce, I would ask the theme devs.

Comment: i disabled theme .. still not working after it.

Comment: disable your plugins,  I (and millions of other people) can add items to my cart in edge/safari/ios

Comment: all plugins disabled, theme disabled, wordpress files updated.. i think it's error in database

Comment: only problem in ms edge and safari,,